# Has any one got camera errors in a widows machine, after using camera to opencv projeccts?

Tags: windows, opencv, image-processing

I was working on an OpenCV project. There I used OpenCV to get video captures and then used some algorithms to face detection and face-swapping. After working on this project for about two weeks, I got errors in my camera (windows camera application). attached one error but sometimes I got different errors as well. I want to know, Did I get those errors due to this OpenCV project?.

[image: sample error]

Answer (score 0):

If your application still runs, you cannot achieve from windows application at the same time. If not, basic reset always saves lives!

- Click Windows key + I to open Settings app.
- Select System>Apps & features and find Camera on the list.
- Click Advanced options link.
- Then press Reset button and wait for the process to be executed.

Secondly, check if the camera works properly from device manager.
[image]

Lastly, try to open from another app(like Skype, discord). Otherwise, update or roll-back driver of the camera.

Comment: Already done but I have the error. I do not need to know about this error. I want to know. is this error due to image processing?